# Парсинг лога ip-адресов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Есть файл с логами ip-адресов. Мне нужно выбрать часто повторяющиеся адреса. Как это сделать? Помогите составить регулярное выражение. ip должен повторяться более тысячи раз. Если более тысячи раз, то мы его подсвечиваем.

Comment: А на каком этапе возникла проблема? Регулярные выражения для поиска ip адресов ищутся за 1 минуту. Например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865817/regex-to-match-an-ip-address

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у метки [скрипт] в описании указано "не использовать".

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании часто повторяющийся? 2 раза, 10? 100? 13% ?

Comment: В файле лога 53000 строк с IP, мне нужно выявить наиболее часто повторяющиеся

Comment: Эта проблема не решается (только) регулярными выражениями. Разбейте строки на подстроки, найдите то, что является IP-адресом, и дальше надо найти часто повторяющиеся строки уже на основе частотности IP-адреса (если я правильно понял). Так что работы - непочатый край. :)

Comment: А если выбрать только те, которые повторяются более ста раз?

Comment: Как писал @stribizhev одним только регулярным выражением не обойтись. На мой взгляд лучший вариант - спарсить ваш файл в базу, а потом сделать выборку с группировкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для IPv4 поиск IP, который встречается 1000 раз или более:

```
((?<!\d)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?!\d))(?=(?:(?:\D++|\d++)+?\1){999})
```

Данную задачу можно решить одним регулярным выражением, но не нужно.
Производительность данного выражения крайне низкая.
Тем не менее это прямой ответ на вопрос.

---

Правильным же подходом будет найти все IP адреса:

```
preg_match_all( "/(?<!\\d)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)(?!\\d)/", $text, $allIPs );
```

Потом перебрать массив `$allIPs` в цикле и посчитать все повторяющиеся значения:

```
$count = Array();
foreach ($allIPs[0] as $k=>$v ) {
    if (!isset( $count[$v] ) $count[$v] = 0;
    $count[$v]++;
};
var_dump( $count );
```

Comment: Одинаковые IP могут встречаться 500 раз, а могут 20. Как в таком случае быть?

Comment: @Николай, это надо было сразу спрашивать **отдельным** вопросом. потому что сортировка и подсчёт строк *никак* не пересекается с извлечением подстроки из строки. задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос, нажав кнопку в правом верхнем углу этой страницы.

Comment: @ReinRaus пишет, что неправильное регулярное выражение

Comment: @Николай отлично. Мы подошли к главной сути вопроса. Прежде чем я приведу довольно таки сложное выражение- давайте окончательно определимся что такое «часто повторяющиеся» ? Как можно дать Вам ответ, если Вы сами не понимаете критерии как это определить.

Comment: Извините, сам не мог до конца сформулировать сначала. ip должен повторяться более тысячи раз. Если более тысячи раз, то мы его подсвечиваем.